# laravel- get value from json decode array

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I have an array like this, after I use `json_decode` (`$json = json_decode($items, true);`), the result looks like this

```
array:1 [
  61 => array:53 [
    "id" => 2790
    "name" => "ABC"
    "created_at" => "2020-12-04 09:43:57.317"
    "updated_at" => "2021-02-16 16:47:16.167"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "remark" => null
   ]
]
```

And  Iwant to get the value from field name, how to do it in Laravel??

I try like this but, get error `Undefined offset name`

```
dd($array['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to access the element you're trying to get to is `$array[61]["name"];`

`$array[61]` will give you:

```
array:53 [
    "id" => 2790
    "name" => "ABC"
    "created_at" => "2020-12-04 09:43:57.317"
    "updated_at" => "2021-02-16 16:47:16.167"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "remark" => null
]
```

Then you can use `["name"]` to access the value you're after.